# How can I pull data from website using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am new at vba coding to pull data from website so generally, I use this code to connect and check item to pull data from website but this code cannot check data via watch in vba with my firm webapp. it show nothing when I add watch to the class so what should I do.[HTML Code from my firm webapp 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7xgY.jpg)

[HTML Code from my firm webapp 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTxBu.jpg)

```
Sub Connect_web()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLdocument
    Dim ele As IHTMLElement
    Dim col As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ele_tmp As IHTMLElement

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    URL = "" ' Cannot provide
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate URL

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Page..."
        DoEvents

        End If

    Loop

    Set doc = ie.Document
    Set ele = doc.getElementByClassName("GDB3EHGDHLC")

end sub
```

Comment: If you insert a picture. Please make it a screenshot at least.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with four things:

1) Instead of `.Navigate` use `.Navigate2`

2) Use a proper wait

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

3) Correct the syntax of your `Set ele` line. You are using `ByClassName`which returns a collection and therefore is plural. You are missing the `s` at the end of `element`.

As you have declared `ele` as singular (element), perhaps first set the collection into a separate variable and index into that collection.

```
Dim eles As Object, ele As Object
Set eles  = doc.getElementsByClassName("GDB3EHGDHLC")
Set ele = eles(0)
```

4) You should always use id over other attributes, if possible, as id is usually quicker for retrieval. There is an id against that class name in your image (highlighted element). I am not going to try and type it all out. Please share your HTML using the snippet tool, by editing your question, so we can relate to your html in answer easily.

```
Set ele = doc.getElementById("gwt-debug-restOfIdStringGoesHere")
```

Comment: Did you try this?